# Cant write records to db from jpa (Object is not a known entity type)

Tags: database, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I started my project using jpa2, the tables where created by jpa.
After while I decided to create the schema using sql script instead of jpa, so I exported the DDL from the DB.

After I execute the sql script for the table creation (ddl) I'm having problems with talking with the DB using jpa.

Currently I'm getting the error "Object XXX is not a known entity type".

It worked before while the jpa created the schema, the JPA Object is mentioned on persistence.xml

Comment: Can you post your persistence.xml ??

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved after removing the webserver cache and tmp directory and restarting it